# What is the purpose of __exact in Django querysets API?

Tags: python, django

What is the purpose of using `__exact` in the Django querysets API?

For example:

```py
>>> Library.objects.filter(id = 15942)
<QuerySet [<Library: bee>]>
>>> Library.objects.filter(id__exact = 15942)
<QuerySet [<Library: bee>]>
```

And:

```py
>>> Library.objects.filter(title = 'bee')
<QuerySet [<Library: bee>]>
>>> Library.objects.filter(title__exact = 'bee')
<QuerySet [<Library: bee>]>
```

Noting that it's apparently not about case sensitivity:

```py
>>> Library.objects.filter(title = 'Bee')
<QuerySet []>
>>> Library.objects.filter(title__exact = 'Bee')
<QuerySet []>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/

**exact**

Exact match. If the value provided for comparison is None, it will be interpreted as an SQL NULL (see isnull for more details).

```
Entry.objects.get(id__exact=14)
Entry.objects.get(id__exact=None)
```

SQL equivalents:

```
SELECT ... WHERE id = 14;
SELECT ... WHERE id IS NULL;
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#exact for the exact (no joke) location in the doc

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `__exact` is always present:

> As a convenience when no lookup type is provided (like in Entry.objects.get(id=14)) the lookup type is assumed to be exact.

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups